# ICCV subfigures/subcaptions not recomended?

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I want to submit a paper to this years `ICCV` conference. However, when I am using their Latex template and try to use a `subfigure` with a `subcaption`

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

I am getting the warning that the caption package is not recommended.

Does this mean that ICCV discourages to use subfigures/subcaptions in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package replaces code from the LaTeX kernel and the document class. Before doing so, it checks if the code it replaces is well known code, and if not, it issues the compatibility warning you have spotted.

How serious one should take this warning? This is hard to tell, at least without knowing the code of ICCV in detail. It could be that a small design decision taken by ICCV will get overwritten, it could be that major design decisions will get overwritten, it could be that some functionality offered by the ICCV class will not work correctly, it could be that the document won't compile at all after including the usage of the `caption` package.

Comment: And what should I use instead in order to still have the subfigure and subcaption functionality, but without overwriting any of their design decisions?

Comment: @LucaThiede You could use `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` instead.